# SQL Server bulk insert with dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert

I'm playing around with the BULK INSERT function of SQL server.

Here's the test data in the .csv that I'm using:

```
2017-06-26,123456,101
2017-06-26,321482,73
2017-06-26,90139,10
```

When running:

```
bulk insert testTable from 'c:\ml\data\test.csv'
```

I receive the following error:

```
Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The 
provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

Comment: If you open your .csv file in an editor like Notepad++ and show whitespace characters, you can make sure each line has the same ending, and that there isn't a 4th line with only whitespace characters. I've seen that cause similar errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To import delimited files it is necessary that you inform the line terminator and also columns

try to execute this.

```
bulk insert testTable 
from 'c:\ml\data\test.csv' 
WITH(FIELDTERMINATOR=',',ROWTERMINATOR='0x0a',CODEPAGE=1252)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I understand the first two parameters, can you help explain CODEPAGE=1252?

Comment: @user3654225 describes the character set used for encoding a particular set of characters, usually combined with a number of control characters.